# Databinding methods such as Eval() can only be used in the context of a databound control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having issues with trying to add a page that will grab an ID. Here is the following code:

```
<td style="width: 20px;">
     <a href="<%= ResolveUrl(String.Format("~/Blah/BlahBlah/{0}",Eval("BobId"))) %>">
           <img src="../../images/Blah.gif" alt="Copy Blah" runat="server" id="BlahCell" style="margin-top: 3px;" />
     </a>
</td>
```

I get the following error: "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control." I've tried a couple of different methods, but I can't seem it get it to function the way I want.

Comment: Where does the ID (BobId) come from? The error message means exactly that; your statement is not inside a databound control so there is nothing for eval to work on.

Comment: So, what is BobId Banana ? Can you post server-side code as well please ?